# I need to filter out words or word groups from a String via Regex

Tags: java, regex

Good evening.
I have a string like "leicht bewölkt leichter Regen Regen". I need a regex pattern that matches "leicht bewölkt" (two adjectives), "leichter Regen" (adjective and noun) and "Regen" (noun). I have found out, how I can match against an adjective "\b[a-z][a-z]*\b", but how can I do that with two adjectives or one adjective and a noun...? I'm a bit lost.
Thanks in advance.

\b[a-z][a-z]*\b

Comment: So you want to match either one word starting with a capital letter or two words, of which the first one must start with a lowercase letter? (mind that most people won't be familiar with german capitalization rules, you should really spell it out)

Comment: Do you have a list of nouns/adjectives or something?

Comment: I am really curious, because your regex does not match for adjectives :D I doubt there are regex for nouns and adjectives. With regex you can check for specific chars, length, upper or lowercase and many more characteristics, but not for adjectives or nouns or similar. If you figure out a rule for adjectives or nouns (nouns could be uppercase, followed by x lowercase letters but no "." at the end) you could make this work. For testing your regex: https://regex101.com/

Comment: No man, regex is a character processor, not a language processor. If you have a list of adjectives and nouns then you can create a full blown regex trie that will string together adjectives and nouns. There is a tool to create such a regex if you have a big list. Let me know if you need it.

Comment: Yeah, I know, I meant by rules like: one word starting with a small letter followed by a word with a capital one and stuff.

Comment: Try looking at natural language parsers. These would be helpful in determining adjectives, nouns etc. Something like https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml .

Answer (score 1):

A regex matching a single full word starting with an uppercase letter is easy to derive from your current regex, just replace the first character class by its uppercase equivalent :

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b
```

Now we only need to combine the two to match the following patterns :

- two words, both starting with lowercase letters (two adjectives)
- two words, the first starting with a lowercase letter, the second with an uppercase (adjective and noun)
- a single word starting with an uppercase letter (noun)

We can represent consecutive words by joining them with a single space character.

A basic solution will be an alternation of the three patterns listed above :

```
\b[a-z][a-z]*\b \b[a-z][a-z]*\b|\b[a-z][a-z]*\b \b[A-Z][a-z]*\b|\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b

^________two adjectives_______^ ^____one adjective one noun___^ ^__one  noun__^
```

It can be improved in multiple ways :

- your regex for a single full lowercase can be written as `\b[a-z]+\b` (`+` is "one or more", which is the same as one and then "0 or more" `*`)
- there automatically is a word boundary between a character of `[a-z]` and a space, therefore the `\b` after a word and before a space and those after a space and before a word can be removed, as they always will be matched if the word and the space are.
- you could factorize the first two patterns as they both start with a lowercase word, or the last two patterns as they both end in a noun. I however think this would reduce readability and therefore maintainability so I will abstain

In conclusion, I would use the following :

```
\b[a-z]+ [a-z]+\b|\b[a-z]+ [A-Z][a-z]*\b|\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b
```

[Testing it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0CcDkD/1) shows you will have problems with non-ascii characters ([`ö` isn't matched by `[a-z]` and isn't considered a word character](https://regex101.com/r/ZauKJO/1), [unless the UNICODE flag is set](https://regex101.com/r/2bSttN/1)).

To handle the unicode problem you can use the `\p{Ll}` "lowercase letters of any language" and `\p{Lu}` "uppercase letters of any language" meta-characters in conjunction with the UNICODE flag / UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS for java (needed for `\b` to work correctly) instead of your current character classes :

```
\b\p{Ll}+ \p{Ll}+\b|\b\p{Ll}+ \p{Lu}\p{L}*\b|\b\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*\b
```

([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2bSttN/2), [java code on ideone](https://ideone.com/mIVIvu))

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it out.

Comment: @DanielHegemann I've updated my answer to handle unicode characters